# How can I get the header of specific pages of word importing using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have an integer pageNumber available, I need to get the header of the page of pageNumber of a word document and paste it in excel

my code is as follows:

```
Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file
pageNumber = 5 //dynamically changes but not important here
pageHeader = wdDoc.Sections(pageNumber).Headers(1).Range.Text
```

the code above works but not consistent, it gets the header of different page not the actual page indicated by pageNumber

I figured because its not actually a Page its calling but Sections. so I changed it to :

```
pageHeader = wdDoc.Pages(pageNumber).Headers(1).Range.Text
```

but it doesn't work. I'm new to vba and I'm struggling to read the documentations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word doesn't have a proper "Pages" object because it doesn't arrange content by page. A page isn't an object that contains content. A page is just whatever content currently fits on it. A document is a long stream of content that gets split across pages depending on what it is and how big it is.

That said, here's a way to try to identify the section number at the start of the specified page, which should identify the header used on that page:

```
sectionNumber = wdDoc.Windows(1).Panes(1).Pages(pageNumber).Rectangles(1).Range.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber)

pageHeader = wdDoc.Sections(sectionNumber).Headers(1).Range.Text
```

wdActiveEndSectionNumber = 2

If you add a reference to the Word object model, you can use Word objects with intellisense in the VBE with early binding and you can also use Word constants. You add references from the Tools > References menu:

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I am currently cannot use wdActiveEndSectionNumber as Im doing this on excel vba, can you provide the constant for it

Comment: It is 2, but you can word constants if you add a reference to the word object model. I've updated answer on how to do that too and you should look into early binding, as it makes coding much easier.

Comment: Thanks Micheal, I'm getting 0 for section number, i think maybe because of the `ActiveWindow`, `wdDoc` is the word object I am using, even though I change it still 0

Comment: Updated to refer to the windows of wdDoc. If it can't find the windows of wdDoc, then you'll need to activate it first using:    wdDoc.Activate

Comment: I've use `.Activate` and its working as intended so far, I'm testing this on all of my documents. Thank you very much Michael!